# Failed to build open jdk 8 from source, ubuntu 18.04, 64bit

Tags: java, ubuntu-18.04

I tried to follow this link to build my own JDK:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html#introduction

To recap the steps are as:

- hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8 YourOpenJDK
- cd YourOpenJDK
- bash ./get_source.sh
- bash ./configure
- make all

In the last step, it showed error like:

```
*** This OS is not supported: Linux compitition2 4.15.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 10 17:58:07 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
/home/jon/Downloads/OpenJDK/hotspot/make/linux/Makefile:234: recipe for target 'check_os_version' failed
make[5]: *** [check_os_version] Error 1
/home/jon/Downloads/OpenJDK/hotspot/make/linux/Makefile:255: recipe for target 'linux_amd64_compiler2/debug' failed
make[4]: *** [linux_amd64_compiler2/debug] Error 2
Makefile:216: recipe for target 'generic_build2' failed
make[3]: *** [generic_build2] Error 2
make[2]: *** [product] Error 2
Makefile:167: recipe for target 'product' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/jon/Downloads/OpenJDK/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/hotspot/_hotspot.timestamp] Error 2
HotspotWrapper.gmk:44: recipe for target '/home/jon/Downloads/OpenJDK/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/hotspot/_hotspot.timestamp' failed
/home/jon/Downloads/OpenJDK//make/Main.gmk:108: recipe for target 'hotspot-only' failed
make: *** [hotspot-only] Error 2
```

my experimental machine is Ubuntu 18.04, 64bit.

cat /etc/*-release

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
```

uanme -a

```
Linux compitition2 4.15.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 10 17:58:07 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Makefile](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/make/linux/Makefile#l228) Kernel 4.X is not supported. The check compares `uname -r` to with version patterns `2.4% 2.5% 2.6% 3%`:

```
SUPPORTED_OS_VERSION = 2.4% 2.5% 2.6% 3%
OS_VERSION := $(shell uname -r)
EMPTY_IF_NOT_SUPPORTED = $(filter $(SUPPORTED_OS_VERSION),$(OS_VERSION))
```

You can try building with `DISABLE_HOTSPOT_OS_VERSION_CHECK` option and see what happens but downgrading to Kernel 3.X is safer. If you want to build old JDK 8 maybe spin up a virtual machine with some older distribution e.g. [Fedora 9 with gcc 4.3.0 as per Supported Build Platforms](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Build/Supported+Build+Platforms).

Comment: Thanks@Karol. I set the env variable now this error was gone. However I ran into another issue relating to C++11 violation. I'll post it in a separate thread - if that doesn't work out I'll consider downgrading the kernel or using an old Linux distro.